# sql increment value on every row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How on earth , do I count a row without using ROW_NUMBER (because I use 15 joins and row_number return stupid values) .

After doing 15 joins .. the query will select 4 or 5 rows and I need to add a counter to them like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I have tried with ROW_NUMBER but it's not suited here ? Is there a function that count on every row outputted ?

I also tried `declare @inc int set @inc = 0` and in the select statement : `select @inc:=@inc+1 as inc` and `select @inc = @inc + 1 as inc` and not working (`Incorrect syntax near ':'.`)

Comment: You should show us your query.

Comment: the query has 150 lines .. and the tables have over 10 milion entry

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` works. Try `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY SameOrderAsQuery)As RowNumber`. It doesn't matter how large your table is.

Comment: I don;t know how to ORDER BY because I want to order by start_date .. and start_date is generated within a `CASE WHEN END as start_date`

Comment: @purfos: You could use the same `CASE` in `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Comment: It outputs values like 3242543 not 1 , 2, 3, 4

Comment: I think you're expecting it to output the rows in the same order as the `ORDER BY` within your `OVER()` clause - this is *not* guaranteed. If you want the rows in a particular order, you need to specify an outer `ORDER BY` (after any `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses). All that the inner `ORDER BY` does is make the `ROW_NUMBER` deterministic.

Comment: why this need to be so complicated ? a simple function would'n be more appropriate ?

Comment: @purfos: `ROW_NUMBER` is a simple function. You only need to apply the same order to your outer query. Otherwise it won't return a consecutive number.

Answer (score 2):

From comments:

[`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) should work,  it doesn't matter how large your table is.

> I don;t know how to ORDER BY because I want to order by start_date ..
>   and start_date is generated within a CASE WHEN END as start_date

You can also use `CASE` in `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER
    ( ORDER BY 
        ( CASE WHEN ... END ) DESC, 
        ( CASE WHEN ... END ) ASC 
    ) AS RowNumber
....
```

**Edit**: I cannot see an `Order By` in your query, so the order  is not predictable(depends on the optimizer). So i would recommend to apply an order by to the outer query, the same as in the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: look .. it output this : 282036, 2140900, 2142724, 2146320

Comment: @pufos: What's wrong with these values? If your query returns so many rows. Maybe you're using the Row_Number in an inner query that is grouped by in an outer.

Comment: I need to return 1, 2, 3, 4, and fast ..

Comment: @pufos: You should order your query(edited my answer).

Comment: I need to be 1, 2, 3, 4, ... not 129348743

Comment: @pufos: i assume that "129348743" should mean "1,2,9,3,4,8,7,4,3". Have you read what i've suggested? Your (outer)query is not ordered, why do you think that an ordered `ROW_NUMBER` returns the same result?

Comment: no ... 12933428732 means 12933....

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is exactly what you want, it just sounds like you are using it wrong - in your `OVER()` you should just have an `ORDER BY`.

Also 15 joins suggests your schema is a bit messy.

Comment: I don;t know how to `ORDER BY` because I want to order by start_date .. and start_date is generated within a `CASE WHEN END as start_date`

Comment: Then nest the part of your query that produces that column into a nested select.  Then you will just have a column name in your outer query.

Comment: It outputs values like 244343 not 1 , 2 , 3 , 4